# Bind Directory.EnumerateFiles to a Repeater using a Generic List

Tags: c#, asp.net, repeater, generic-list

I am trying to create a small web app, that when I type in a game name, it will search through a folder with a whole lot of icons to find one similar to the typed in game.

I then want to show a repeater with the name of the icon, as well as the icon next to it.

So far I have successfully displayed the name with this code:

```
IEnumerable<string> getfiles =
            from f in
                Directory.EnumerateFiles(Server.MapPath("~/_resources/game_icon"), "*.*", SearchOption.AllDirectories)
            where Path.GetFileName(f).ToLower().Contains(txtGameName.Text.ToLower())
            select Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(f);

        List<AllFiles> all = getfiles.Select(file => new AllFiles
            {
                FileName = file, 
                SubdirectoryName = "",
                FileNameWithExtension = ""
            }).ToList();

        rptGameMatches.DataSource = all;
        rptGameMatches.DataBind();
```

But havent had much luck in displaying the icon, which would be in `ImageLocation`.

Ive tried playing with:

```
foreach (string file in Directory.EnumerateFiles(Server.MapPath("~/_resources/game_icon"), "*.*", SearchOption.AllDirectories).Count() )
        {
            if(file.)
        }
```

and

```
for (int i = 0; i < Directory.EnumerateFiles(Server.MapPath("~/_resources/game_icon"), "*.*", SearchOption.AllDirectories).Count(); i++)
        {

        }
```

With no success.

I know there is a simplistic way to do this, but I cant quite seem to get it right. Could someone please show me where I'm going wrong?

Comment: Why are you creating an `AllFiles` which basically has the same data twice? And why are you expecting to be able to use the result of `Count()` as the source in a `foreach` loop?

Comment: No, those last 2 were just me playing around with the idea, so you can see I was at least attempting a solution.
In my mind, I need to put it in a generic list to bind the name and path correctly to the repeater. I am open to hearing im totally wrong, though.

Comment: So each entry should be `{ "foo.png", "c:\Whatever\Bar.path" }`? Bear in mind that if you want to provide images, you'll need URLs rather than file paths.

Comment: The entry I'm looking for will be `{ "foo", "/_resources/game_icon/" + "foo.png" }`. I need the File name (with out extension - because there are different extensions in the folders) for the file name, and the file name with extension for the image location.  [EDIT] I realised now that I need another DirectoryName variable, because the images are in sub directories. I am using http://imageresizing.net/ to display my images.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's an example of what you could do (for compactness reasons I have placed the code behind and the markup inside a single WebForm but of course you could have the code behind in a separate file):

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" %>
<%@ Import Namespace="System.IO" %>

<script type="text/c#" runat="server">
    protected void BtnSearchClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var images =
            from image in Directory.EnumerateFiles(Server.MapPath(folder), "*.*", SearchOption.AllDirectories)
            let relativeLocation = image.Replace(root, string.Empty).Replace("\\", "/")
            let url = ResolveUrl("~/" + relativeLocation)
            where image.ToLower().Contains(txtGameName.Text.ToLower())
            select new 
            {
                Url = url
            };

        results.DataSource = images;
        results.DataBind();
    }
</script>

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
        <asp:TextBox ID="txtGameName" runat="server" />
        <asp:LinkButton ID="btnSearch" runat="server" OnClick="BtnSearchClick" Text="Search" />
        <asp:Repeater ID="results" runat="server">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:Image runat="server" ImageUrl='<%# Eval("Url") %>' />
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:Repeater>
    </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Alright, so we have a web page containing a text field, a button and a repeater. When the button is clicked we are searching for all images in the specified folder whose name contains the text entered into the text field:

```
var images =
    from image in Directory.EnumerateFiles(Server.MapPath(folder), "*.*", SearchOption.AllDirectories)
    let relativeLocation = image.Replace(root, string.Empty).Replace("\\", "/")
    let url = ResolveUrl("~/" + relativeLocation)
    where image.ToLower().Contains(txtGameName.Text.ToLower())
    select new 
    {
        Url = url
    };
```

There are a few steps here:

```
let filename = Path.GetFileName(image)
```

at this stage we are getting the physical location to the file. It will look like this:

```
c:\inetpub\wwwroot\_resources\game_icon\image1.png
```

Then we strip the application root and replace the slashes:

```
let relativeLocation = filename.Replace(root, string.Empty).Replace("\\", "/")
```

so `relativeLocation` becomes:

```
_resources/game_icon/image1.png
```

and the last step is:

```
let url = ResolveUrl("~/" + relativeLocation)
```

which will turn that into:

```
/_resources/game_icon/image1.png
```

So at the end of the day the images collection might look like this (assuming the user searched for `image` in the text field):

```
[
    { Url: "/_resources/game_icon/image1.png" },
    { Url: "/_resources/game_icon/subfolder1/image2.png" },
    { Url: "/_resources/game_icon/subfolder2/image1.png" },
    ...
]
```

It is this collection that is bound to the repeater. Inside the repeater we have defined an Image whose `ImageUrl` property will be data bound to the `Url` property of the anonymous object we constructed.

Comment: The main thing I like about this is the fact that you actually explained the process step-by-step. Thank you for that! I see your method, but I also need to display the file name, and remember the files are in subdirectories.

Comment: This is an amazing example of what I want, thank you. The only thing I added was `let filename = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(image)` in the `from`, and `Filename = filename,` in the `select`. Then `<%# Eval("Filename") %> - <%# Eval("Url") %>` in the `.aspx`. Thank you very much.

Comment: Bit of an issue - the page isnt showing the file URL with a subdirectory. eg : Instead of `/_resources/game_icon/subdir/icon.png`, its displaying `/_resources/game_icon/icon.png`