# Display an image with a special character in the url

Tags: c#, asp.net, special-characters

With [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14332397/bind-directory-enumeratefiles-to-a-repeater-using-a-generic-list), I am reading a folder of images, then displaying those images on a web page.

Currently, it all works, except for images with a special character.

Names with an '&' sign show a broken image link. Is there any way I can show the image without having to change the image name?

I've tried

```
var images =
            from image in Directory.EnumerateFiles(Server.MapPath("~/_resources/game_icon"), "*.*", SearchOption.AllDirectories)
            let filename = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(image)
            let relativeLocation = Path.GetFullPath(image).Replace(Server.MapPath("~"), string.Empty).Replace("\\", "/")//.Replace(Path.GetFileName(image), HttpUtility.UrlEncode(Path.GetFileName(image)))
            let splitted= string.Join("/", relativeLocation.Split('/').ToList().Select(p => Server.UrlEncode(p)))
            let url = ResolveUrl("~/" + splitted)
            where image.ToLower().Contains(txtGameName.Text.ToLower())
            select new
            {
                Filename = filename,
                Url = url
            };
```

But all images break.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out it was just a `A potentially dangerous Request.Path value was detected from the client` error.

Using

```
<system.web>
    <httpRuntime requestPathInvalidCharacters="&lt;,&gt;,%,&amp;,:,\,?" />
</system.web>
```

Fixes all issues.

Answer (score 1):

I believe that in this case it is better to use Server.UrlEncode. Here's a link http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zttxte6w(v=vs.100).aspx

Comment: `Server.UrlEncode` also changes the `/` in the URL, which then breaks every image.

Answer (score 0):

Use HttpServerUtility.HtmlEncode on the image name.  See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w3te6wfz.aspx

Comment: I cant access that in a static context. This happens on a button click. Using `Server.HtmlEncode` also doesnt work.

Comment: The image is still broken. The image URL is now `<img src="/OCDB/_resources/game_icon/Beyond%20-%20Good%20&amp;amp;%20Evil_1.png" style="width:50px;border-width:0px;">`

Comment: Yes use HttpUtility.UrlEncode as @Timur suggests.  Sorry, I had a senior moment.

Comment: None of the images display if I use that. `<img src="%2fOCDB%2f_resources%2fgame_icon%2fBionic+Commando+Rearmed_1.png" style="width:50px;border-width:0px;">` This image worked until `UrlEncode`

Comment: Presumably you need to run UrlEncode on each individual component of the path, something like `string.Join("/", path.Split('/').ToList().Select(p => Server.UrlEncode(p)))`

Comment: I've updated my question with this. Am I even doing it right?